# How to query Seriel Port Names in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arduino, basic

[image: Picture of Arduino IDE]

Hi all,

I have written a VB application that puts all available com ports in a combobox, but I want to include the name of the device on the seriel port, as well as the com port it is on. This makes it easier to locate which com port my arduino is on.

Has anyone come across a way of doing this? Or is it something that is unique to the arduino IDE.

Thanks

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
Imports System.Management

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(
                            "root\CIMV2",
                            "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=""{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}""")

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj("Name"))
        Next

    Catch err As ManagementException
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
    End Try
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

Now, with your Arduino plugged in, when you run that code it should display 'usb-serial ch340' in the command window. If you do a search for this on the web it comes back with a bunch of results for  Arduino.... So, I'm guessing that 'usb-serial ch340' maps to an  'Arduino/Genuino Uno' device, if you plug in a different device it will return a different result....